# Find the number of cities with one outgoing road

Tags: math, cities-skylines-api

I'm practicing for my entrance exam. There are some sample tests available for candidates and I want to solve them before appearing for the exam. But facing problem with the following question.
If anyone can help me solve this, would be highly appreciated.

There are 15 main cities in one country. Some of them are connected by roads. 
Besides,

a) You can get from each one city to any other one by a single route;

b) There is only one city with 2 outgoing roads. The other cities have either 
1 or 3 outgoing roads.

What is the number of cities with one outgoing road?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of a) we can say that this is a tree structure. And in trees the number of edges are one less than number of nodes. Therefore there are only 14 roads. If the number of cities with one outgoing road is x, then `1 * x + 2 * 1 + 3 * (14 - x) = 2 * 14` Which gives us `x = 8`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One thing to ask, I understand the left hand side but confused about the right hand side. (2 * 14). 14 is the total number of roads, what is 2 here?

Comment: 2 is basically due to binary tree structure?

Comment: Left hand side is number of outgoing roads. 14 is number of roads. But total number of outgoing roads is twice the number of roads. Because a single road is outgoing road of two cities on each side.